# trying to display 2 character variables alphabetically

Tags: javascript, variables, character

tried to solve below statement and getting into issue, declared 2 character variable and not sure how to display them alphabetically.
Declare two character variables and give them values. Use an if statement to write them in alphabetical order.

```
    var light1 = green;
    var light2 = red;
    if (light1 > light2) {
    document.write("demo");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<` to lexicographically compare the strings to display them in alphabetical order (assuming they're both lowercase or both uppercase). As you can see, `b` is greater than `a`:

```js
console.log("b" > "a");
console.log("a" > "b");
```

So to print them alphabetically, just do this:

```js
const firstVariable = "a";
const secondVariable = "b";

if (firstVariable < secondVariable) {
  console.log(firstVariable, secondVariable);
} else {
  console.log(secondVariable, firstVariable);
}
```